# [Sony Xperia XZ1]Remapping camera button

Tags: root-access, custom-roms, buttons, scripts

Hello {darkness my old friend}
I have a Sony Xperia XZ1(G8341) with AOSP GSI

What I would kindly like to ask  how to map the "dead" camera button to any function

Currently the button doesn't work at all presumably because my custom rom didnt hsve plans for it

Tried any root app i could find, msgidk modules and others however i wourld prefer not using xposed as it gives negative results on ctsProfile

Any suggestion is welcome since I have a throughout knowledge and understanding of technology in general ,you can trust me on that{pushes pile of softbricked deviced under bed} but i would prefer being guided to the right direction on how to make s script to accomplish that

Thank you in advance

Comment: Tried this app? https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=flar2.homebutton

Comment: Yes I have, unkown(0) when i try to add the button, on settings both "alternative" settings fail, combination of those settings fail as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.irishin.buttonsremapper

It works on my Xperia x compact. It's just a workaround. On my phone the problem is with camera button that was deasappeared after the rom unlocking aldo with drm fixed in...